# JMeter did not stop automatically when trying to run from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

```
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
!! get trust managers (X509)
... end of run
The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[com.hivemq.client.mqtt-1-2,5,main], stackTrace:io.netty.channel.epoll.Native#epollWait0
io.netty.channel.epoll.Native#epollWait at line:114
io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop#epollWait at line:253
io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop#run at line:278
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5#run at line:909
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable#run at line:30
java.lang.Thread#run at line:748
```

We tried running the JMeter from non-GUI mode(via Jenkins) but after the specified duration, the job did not stop. And the above-mentioned logs were printed on the Jenkins console output. The JMeter version is **5.4.3** and the Jenkins version is **Jenkins 2.239**. Can anyone tell us what is the issue and the steps to resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your console output contains the answer:

> The following non-daemon threads **are still running** (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
> **Thread[com.hivemq.client.mqtt-1-2,5,main], stackTrace:io.netty.channel.epoll.Native#epollWait0**

The thread which waits for [MQTT](https://mqtt.org/) message cannot be terminated, so in order to resolve the same you need to see your code/plugin/whatever to see what's going on there and to introduce reasonable [timeouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeout_(computing)) for the same.

You may also find [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide) article useful.